# Prove $b^{2} (\cot A + \cot B) = c^{2}(\cot A + \cot C)$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

In any triangle  $ABC $ prove that  $$b^{2} (\cot A + \cot B) = c^{2}(\cot A + \cot C)$$
How we can prove this trigonometric identity.  I tried many ways and use the other well known identity but it wasn't work. My question is how we can prove this trigonometric identity?. Any hint will help  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

We have 
$$\cot A+\cot B=\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}
=\frac{\cos A\sin B+\sin A\cos B}{\sin A\sin B}$$

Now, by using the formula $\sin (A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B\,\,\,\,$ and $\,\,\,\,\sin C=\sin (\pi-C)$ we get

$$b^2(\cot A+\cot B)=\frac{b^2\sin (A+B)}{\sin A\sin B}=\frac{b^2\sin C}{\sin A\sin B}...(1)$$

In a similar way we get

$$c^2(\cot A+\cot C)=\frac{c^2\sin B}{\sin A\sin C}...(2)$$

In order to prove that $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal it will be sufficient to prove:
$$\frac{b^2\sin C}{\sin B}=\frac{c^2\sin B}{\sin C}$$
Which is equivalent to
$$\frac{b^2}{\sin^2 B}=\frac{c^2}{\sin^2 C}$$

And the last equality holds due to Sine Law.

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice proof of this trig identity.

Notice, in right $\triangle ABC$  $(A+B+C=180^\circ)$ we know from sine rule $$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=k$$ 
$$\implies \ a=k\sin A, \  b=k\sin B, \ c=k\sin C, $$
Now, we have $$LHS=b^2(\cot A+\cot B)$$
$$=(k\sin B)^2\left(\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}+\frac{\cos B}{\sin B}\right)$$
$$=k^2\sin^2B \left(\frac{\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}{\sin A\sin B}\right)$$
$$=k^2 \frac{\sin B\sin (A+B)}{\sin A}$$
 $$=k^2 \frac{\sin (180^\circ-(A+C))\sin (180^\circ-C)}{\sin A}$$
 $$=k^2 \frac{\sin (A+C)\sin C}{\sin A}$$

$$=k^2\sin^2 C \left(\frac{\sin A\cos C+\cos A\sin C}{\sin A\sin C}\right)$$
 $$=(k\sin C)^2 \left(\frac{\cos C}{\sin C}+\frac{\cos A}{\sin A}\right)$$
setting the value $k\sin C=c$ from (1) $$=\color{}{(c)^2(\cot C+\cot A)}$$
$$LHS=\color{red}{c^2(\cot A+\cot C)}=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a *trigonograph* for non-obtuse $B$ and $C$:

[image]

> $$|\overline{AB}||\overline{ED}| = |\square AEDF| = |\overline{AC}||\overline{FD}| \quad\to\quad c^2\,\left(\, \cot A + \cot C \,\right) = b^2\,\left(\,\cot A + \cot B\,\right)$$